# Stop the jQueryUI Slider after a specific difference/margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a Margin or we can say a Specific distance changed from HTML select option tag in future dynamically..
I have created a Range Slider with [jQueryUI Slider](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider).

**What i am trying to do :**
I want to stop sliding after a specific distance means margin.
Need help .

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/3j3Um/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 95,
        values: [20, 80],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
           var getMargin = ui.values[0] - ui.values[1];
            $("#margin").val(getMargin);
            if (getMargin == -30) {
                alert('stop the sliding');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can use stop event for that. Check this link http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-stop

Comment: i think this event will work after the Slider stoped.

Comment: What do you mean by "Margin or we can say a Specific distance changed from HTML select option tag in future dynamically"? the distance of slide from another element with respect to it's position in window, or something else?

Comment: By the way, everything has it's place in jsfiddle. Only the code inside `<body>` is required inside the html area. Styles goes in styles section. You can select frameworks such as jquery and jquery ui without using script tags using frameworks dropdown, or link to it using external resources. there is a nice **tidy up** option too. Didn't you see the warnings? or are we supposed to do the clean up..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing it alright , you just need to add `return` statement on the condition met. And also you need to change the comparison operator to (`<`) Since **slide** function is invoked every-time a slide action is performed.

I have modified a bit of code to make it work(not clean but you can change it later) :

```
var getMargin = ui.values[0] - ui.values[1];
var rangeValue = (-1) * parseInt(getMargin);
if(rangeValue < 30){
         return false;
  }
$("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
$("#margin").val(getMargin);
```

### And you can check this [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3j3Um/5/)